# Can't change DropDownList SelectedValue when Enabled = False in codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Good afternoon,

I have a DropDownList that I am setting Enabled = false in the code behind OnPageLoad. Later when I press the save button on the page I try to extract the data and I get a weird value from the disabled DropDownList and correct values from the Enabled DropDownList's.

My question is, how can I disable the DropDownList OnPageLoad so the users can't change the data but still modify it's data in the code behind file and extract it when needed? I see that the enabled property sets the read-only flag and I tried enabling the drop down before modifying it's data but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Code behind:

> ```
>     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {  
>         for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(txtNumPrizes.Text.Trim()); i++)
>         {
>             DropDownList dl = new DropDownList();
>             bool disableRow = true; //example
>
>             dl.ID = "DDPrize" + i.ToString();
>             dl.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
>             dl.DataTextField = "PrizeName";
>             dl.DataValueField = "PrizeID";
>             Panel1.Controls.Add(dl);
>             dl.DataBind();
>             if (disableRow == true)
>             {
>                 dl.Enabled = false;
>             }
>
>         } 
>     }
>
>     protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     { 
>         for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(txtNumPrizes.Text.Trim()); i++)
>         {
>             DropDownList dd = (DropDownList)Panel1.FindControl("DDPrize" + i.ToString());
>
>             //disable the row if prize was already assigned to a player
>             int place = 1; //example
>
>             int selectedValue = DropDownSelect(i, place, GetTournamentID());
>             dd.SelectedValue = selectedValue.ToString(); //sets properly here
>
>         } 
>     }
> ```

```
        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= numPrizes; i++)
            {
                DropDownList dd = (DropDownList)Panel1.FindControl("DDPrize" + i.ToString());
                string key = dd.SelectedValue;//here is where we can't get the selected value :(
            }

        }
```

Comment: Show us the code maybe? Also, what is the point of having the dropdown if the users can't interact with it?

Comment: We init in page load we set in page renderer and we get garbage value in btnsave.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable it in code, then when it renders they can't change the selection. The SelectedItem will possibly be null/Nothing depending on whether you set any of the items to Selected=true.

It doesn't make much sense [to me, anyway] using a dropdown that can't be used. Unless of course it's waiting on a postback for enabling it based on certain criteria.

You could disable it with jQuery on page load, and .NET wouldn't care. No matter what, it will let you access the value, **or lack thereof**, which is what you might be missing. Again, you'll still run into the issue that there's no SelectedItem if you haven't set one in the web form or in code.

Posting the code will help us help you further :)

Comment: Mind showing me the code for how to do this based on the code I have posted above?

Comment: Where is it dying in the loop? Does it even get through a single iteration? Also, you should probably only build the textbox If Not Page.IsPostBack, otherwise you're recreating it every time and probably wiping it out of viewstate, or getting duplicate entries, which would [I think...] give you an array of results for each found entry.